# Write a bash script that lists all files and subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, pipeline, ls, cp

I want to write a easy script shell like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

from_directory="first_directory"
to_directory="second_directory"

rsync --archive $(from_directory) $(to_directory) | ls -R $(to_directory)/$(from_directory)
```

OR

```
cp -r $(from_directory) $(to_directory) | ls -R $(to_directory)/$(from_directory)
```

I have this error ==> ls: impossible to reach in / home / jilambo / week2 / shooter_game: no file or directory of this type.

In the second time, it's ok because the first_directory have been copied to the segond directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Be very careful with symbolic links, especially with circular ones. I've seen somebody filling up the disk with a script that followed a symbolic link pointing to the parent directory.

Comment: Use `${from_directory}` instead of `$(from_directory)`, etc. $(foo) means "run the command foo".

Comment: And you probably want `;` instead of `|`. `ls` doesn't read from a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, you probaly want this.

```
#!/bin/bash

from_directory="first_directory"
to_directory="second_directory"

rsync --archive $from_directory $to_directory; ls -R $to_directory/$from_directory
```

And if `$from_directory` and `$to_directory` are both absolute paths, `$to_directory/$from_directory` does not make sense. Might as well just do `ls -R $to_directory`.